# How to convert JSON to Javascript array?

Tags: javascript, json

I need to convert JSON data string to a JavaScript array.
This my JSON data:

```
[["Claim","1"],["issue","4"]]
```

And i want to get

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

        data.addColumn('string' , 'category');
        data.addColumn('number' , 'count');
        data.addRows([
            ['Claim', 1],
            ['Issue', 4]
        ]);
```

Comment: Could you please clarify, what issue are you facing with current code?

Answer (score 0):

The `JSON.parse()` method parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string. An optional reviver function can be provided to perform a transformation on the resulting object before it is returned.

```
const jsonDataStr = '[["Claim","1"],["issue","4"]]'
const jsonDataJSON = JSON.parse(jsonDataStr)
```

For more detail about `JSON.parse()`, you can see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Answer (score 0):

var data = JSON.parse(jsonString);